# Copy constructor invokes infinite loop although having call by reference

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

The code invoking the loop:

```
Foo temp = Foo(token.substr(0,i));
this->leftExpression = temp;
```

Having `Foo` declared as:

```
class Foo{
    private:
        std::string expr;
        std::vector <Bar*> tokens;
        std::vector <std::string> stringtoken;
```

And the CCTOR invoking the loop:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& a_expr){
    this->expr = a_expr.expr;
    this->tokens = a_expr.tokens;
    this->stringtoken = a_expr.stringtoken;
}
```

What is invoking this loop?

EDIT:

Assignment operator:

```
Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo& a_expr){
    Foo temp(a_expr);
    std::swap(*this, temp);
    return (*this);
}
```

Comment: I can only tell you one thing: It's not caused by the code you are showing to us.

Comment: Please paste an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you're posted (although the copy is unnecessary; why not just write `Foo temp(...);`?). Could you post a complete test case to demonstrate the error?

Comment: Show us the constructor invoked by `Foo(token.substr(0,i));` because `token.substr(0,i)` definitely isn't `const Foo&`. Also, if `this->leftExpression = temp;` is part of the problem, show us the implementation of `Foo::operator=(const Foo&)`.

Comment: Are you sure it's calling the copy ctor? Is token a `Foo`?

Comment: Is the problem caused by `this->leftExpression = temp;`? That's calling the copy-assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: as [Lazlo Papp remarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199928/copy-constructor-invokes-infinite-loop-although-having-call-by-reference#comment35486110_23199928), please post a short, self-contained example that we can compile and run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
std::swap(*this, temp);
```

The default implementation of `std::swap` uses assignment, hence the infinite recursion when calling it from your assignment operator.

If you really need to write your own assignment operator, then write your own `swap`, for example:

```
void Foo::swap(Foo & other) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(expr, other.expr);
    // and for all other members
}

Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo temp){
    this->swap(temp);
    return (*this);
}
```

In this case, it looks like all the members are correctly copyable (although you might need to be careful of the dumb pointers in `tokens`). If that is the case, then there's no need to write your own destructor, copy constructor or copy-assignment operator at all - just let the implicit ones do the right thing.

Comment: Does this mean that the way I implemented the `operator=` will never work under any conditions?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie See the link in my answer about the copy-and-swap-idiom which explains how to do it correctly.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: It could work if you specialised `std::swap` for your class. That would be a rather convoluted way to do it though. You can read more about the copy and swap idiom [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543).

Comment: @DanielFrey apparently I misunderstood it, because that is was what I read before coming up with this implementation.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie I see. Well, read it again and also use Mike's example implementation above until you understand the difference then. :) Mike: +1

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: The example there implements `swap` as a non-member (friend) function, then calls `swap(*this, other)` - **not** `std::swap`. That's very similar to my example of a member function - and in some ways better, since it overloads `std::swap`.

Answer (score 1):

Aaaand there's your problem: The assignment operator creates a copy and calls `std::swap`, which in turn calls the assignment operator.

You could either implement the assignment operator without using `std::swap`, or you could implement `swap` without using the default implementation and instead use the ["copy-and-swap"-idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).